# Delphi Infopower Grid with dbNavigator

Tags: delphi, informix

I have a infoPower Grid that is bound to the TQuery Component with following sql

```
SELECT membership_number, message_id, msgText,target, date_time_creation, 
date_time_display
FROM MessageMembership
WHERE membership_number = :membershipnumber
ORDER BY date_time_display desc
```

qalso I have bind it to the dbnavigator as well as DataSource which is binded with The InfoPOwer Grid. Now insert and delete and update buttons are enable but insert button dont let me type the new values also update button dnt let me type the updated value. But delete is working as expected. What can be possible issue or step I am missing?

The code for executing TQuery is :

```
 MessageMembershipSelectQuery.ParamByName('membershipnumber').AsString :=    
 custQuery.FieldByName('cust_code').AsString;
  MessageMembershipSelectQuery.Open;
```

Please help me.

Comment: You haven't followed Jan Doggen's advice to abandon the BDE and use datasets that haven't been obsolete for over a decade, then?  Have you checked whether the TQuery's dataset is read-only?

Comment: @Akshay a lot of the things you are trying to do are quite basic. That is fine, I understand your initial learning curve is steep. But have you seen all the tutorial stuff at delphi.about.com? E.g. if you Google 'delphi dbnavigator site:about.com' you find Zarko's posts about using DBNavigator. Maybe it helps you get a grip with this database stuff by browsing around that site.

Comment: Looks like your `membershipnumber` is a `Integer` not a `String` .

Comment: It is a string actually.

Answer (score 0):

`TQuery` is a **BDE** dataset. It won´t let you edit it´s contents unless the `RequestLive` property is set to `True` and you have a `TUpdateSQL` component bound to it, by the `UpdateObject` property. Those two properties work together to enable the batch mode of BDE, which is named **cached updates**.

However, I strongly advise you to not invest in BDE, not even to learn how to program in Delphi. Much better is to start studing the way of `TClientDataset`. It´s a much more functional dataset that will give you more control over all parts of your application, from selecting to updating data.

The nice thing about `TClientDataset` is that you will isolate the SQL dependecy of your application away from the main domain logic, which will be written all around `TClientDataset`. That logic will be data-dependent, not SQL-dependent.

Think about it: now you have an application that works with MySQL. Then, suddenly, you have to port it to work with Oracle. If you isolate your SQL dependency away from the main code, this refactoring will be much faster and safer.

Remember: **BDE is dead**.

Comment: Dear Sir
Thanks for that but I have to use BDE. 
1) I have Set Request Live Property True
2) Cached Update Property to true.
and Its is binding properly with the database.
Please tell what else I need to do or you require more information?

Comment: @AkshayJamwal: ok, use BDE, but coworking with a `TClientDataset` and a `TDatasetProvider`. `TClientDataset` will prevent you of having *all* these problems and your application will be ready to get rid of BDE when you can. Considering all you just said, I can´t see a good reason to not being able to edit the dataset record in a dataware component, so this is the best I can say. Sorry!